# One more time...can I have an example of state monad that does what I want?

Tags: haskell, state-monad, reader-monad

I'm trying to understand the actual need for the reader and/or state monads. All the examples I've seen (including many on stackoverflow as I've hunted for suitable examples I can use and in various books and blog articles) are of the form (pseudo code)

```
 f = do
        foo <- ask
        do something with foo

 g = do
        foo <- ask
        do something else using foo

 h = runReader
       (
           f
           g
       )
```

In other words, call two functions and (presumably) maintain some state from one call to the next. However, I don't find this example particularly convincing as (I think) I could just have f return some state and then pass that state on to g.

I'd love to see an example, using a single integer (say) as the state to be preserved where, rather than two sequential calls to f and then g from a central place, rather there's a call to f which then internally calls g and then have changed state (if state monad) available back in the main routine.

Most (well actually all) the examples I have seen spend a tremendous amount of time focusing on the definition of the monad and then show how to set up a single function call. To me, it would be the ability to do nested calls and have the state carried along for the ride to demonstrate why it's useful.

Comment: f can call g, no problem, nothing special needs to be done.

Comment: By the way, all uses of `Reader` will be trivial. It's exactly the same thing as just passing an argument. It doesn't even get returned! `ReaderT`, on the other hand, is a bit more useful.

Comment: Actually the reason I was investigating this stuff was because I was trying to avoid having to pass extra arguments all over the place. I was experimenting with having some global parameters being accessible to lots of functions.

Comment: Thank you everyone who responded. Much to digest --- I wish I could tick ALL the answers as correct since they're all incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost everything you can do with monads you can do without them. (Well, some are special like `ST`, `STM`, `IO`, etc., but that's a different story.) But:

- they allow you to encapsulate many common patterns, like in this case stateful computations, and hide details or boiler-plate code that would be otherwise needed; and
- there are plethora of functions that work on any (or many) monads, which you can just specialize for a particular monad you're using.

To give an example: Often one needs to have some kind of a generator that supplies unique names, like when generating code etc. This can be easily accomplished using the state monad: Each time `newName` is called, it outputs a new name and increments the internal state:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Tree
import qualified Data.Traversable as T

type NameGen = State Int

newName :: NameGen String
newName = state $ \i -> ("x" ++ show i, i + 1)
```

Now let's say we have [a tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) that has some missing values. We'd like to supply them with such generated names. Fortunately, there is a generic function [`mapM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v%3amapM) that allows to traverse any traversable structure with any monad (without the monad abstraction, we wouldn't have this function). Now fixing the tree is easy. For each value we check if it's filled (then we just use `return` to lift it into the monad), and if not, supply a new name:

```
fillTree :: Tree (Maybe String) -> NameGen (Tree String)
fillTree = T.mapM (maybe newName return)
```

Just imagine implementing this function without monads, with explicit state - going manually through the tree and carrying the state around. The original idea would be completely lost in boilerplate code. Moreover, the function would be very specific to `Tree` and `NameGen`.

But with monads, we can go even further. We could parametrize the name generator and construct even more generic function:

```
fillTreeM :: (Monad m) => m String -> Tree (Maybe String) -> m (Tree String)
fillTreeM gen = T.mapM (maybe gen return)
```

Note the first parameter `m String`. It's not a constant `String` value, it's a recipe for generating a new `String` within `m`, whenever it's needed.

Then the original one can be rewritten just as

```
fillTree' :: Tree (Maybe String) -> NameGen (Tree String)
fillTree' = fillTreeM newName
```

But now we can use the same function for many very different purposes. For example, use the [`Rand` monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) and supply randomly generated names.

Or, at some point we might consider a tree without filled out nodes invalid. Then we just say that wherever we're asked for a new name, we instead abort the whole computation. This can be implemented just as

```
checkTree :: Tree (Maybe String) -> Maybe (Tree String)
checkTree = fillTreeM Nothing
```

where `Nothing` here is of type `Maybe String`, which, instead of trying to generate a new name, aborts the computation within the `Maybe` monad.

This level of abstraction would be hardly possible without having the concept of monads.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a non-trivial example of a stateful subroutine calling another stateful subroutine.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

f :: State Int ()
f = do
    r <- g
    modify (+ r)

g :: State Int Int
g = do
    modify (+ 1)
    get

main = print (execState f 4)
```

In this example, the initial state begins at `4` and the stateful computation begins at `f`.  `f` internally calls `g`, which increments the state to `5` and then returns the current state (still `5`).  This restores control to `f`, which binds the value `5` to `r` and then increments the current state by `r`, giving a final state of `10`:

```
>>> main
10
```

Comment: Thank you --- three questions.  One: can g now call a new function h which also does modifications that propagate back to main? Two: suppose I have a bunch of regular function calls (e.g,   add x y = x + y). Can I call those things directly from inside g (or h) and still have the result propagated all the way back? Three: assuming yes to all of these, how exactly is the state being passed to and from those functions and what happens if there are other regular arguments?

Comment: `State s r` is isomorphic to `s -> (r, s)` and the threading of state is done in the natural way.  The main advantage of the Monad is being able to use do syntax and other Functor/Monad-generic functions.

Comment: @David I encourage you to re-implement `State` yourself as an exercise. It's really not hard, and I expect it will completely clear up all the questions you just asked. You can steal the definition of the `State` type from the standard libraries; then implement the functorial and monadic functions and the state retrieval and update functions by yourself.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the definition in the standard libraries is no longer beginner-friendly—it's defined using `StateT`.

Comment: @dfeuer Ah, right. Okay, then I amend my suggestion: start with `newtype State s a = State (s -> (s, a))`.

Comment: @David Answer to #1: Yes, noting that `main` has no concept of `State`.  Answer to #2: It does not matter "when" functions are evaluated.  Answer to #3: Read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad).

Comment: @dfeuer --- the problem is that nothing in those libraries is beginner friendly.

Comment: @Gabriel --- thanks for answers. Regarding #2, I was actually thinking in terms of having to lift functions, not concerned about the laziness aspect. Rearding #3, by "how" I actually meant implementation. When f calls g (say), how does the "State" part become accessible to g? In other words, is there an equivalent of the hidden "self" or "this" being sent around under the covers? What happens if you have two sets of state?

Comment: @David, there are no real covers. A value of type `State s a` is a state *transformer*. It is (under a thin little `newtype` wrapper that's useful for the class system) just a *function* that takes a state and gives a new state and some sort of result. The monadic `>>=` operator is what "hides" things, in the sense that you don't have to explicitly handle the state from the time you feed it in at the beginning to the time you pull it out at the end. But there's nothing magical about `>>=`. You can (and should) implement it yourself for the definition of `State` Daniel Wagner gives above.

Comment: In order to define that type, you'll have to refrain from importing the actual `State` module, but that's okay. You're defining that type in order to learn; you can try to learn to use that module later (as I will....). Start with `instance Monad (State s)` and go from there.

Comment: There is nothing magic happening under the covers.  A value of type `State s a` is, under the hood, literally just a function of type `s -> (a, s)` and `do` notation combines these functions together.  What's neat is that you combine two stateful functions you get back a new stateful function.  This is the reason why you can nest `State` actions within each other indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to understand the actual need for the reader and/or state monads.

There are many ways to understand monads in general, and these monads in particular. In this answer, I focus on one understanding of these monads which I believe might be helpful for the OP.

The reader and state monads provide library support for very simple usage patterns:

- The reader monad provides support for passing arguments to functions.
- The state monad provides support for getting results out of functions and passing them to other functions.

As the OP correctly figured out, there is no great need for library support for these things, which are already very easy in Haskell. So many Haskell programs *could* use a reader or state monad, but there's no point in doing so, so they don't.

So why would anyone ever use a reader or state monad? I know three important reasons:

1. Realistic programs contain many functions that call each other and pass information back and forth. Sometimes, many functions take arguments that are just passed on to other functions. The reader monad is a library for this "accept arguments and pass them on" pattern. The state monad is a library for the similar "accept arguments, pass them on, and pass the results back as my result" pattern.

   In this situation, a benefit of using the reader or state monad is that the arguments get passed on automatically, and we can focus on the more interesting jobs of these functions. A cost is that we have to use monadic style (do notation etc.).
2. Realistic programs can use multiple monads at once. They need arguments that are passed on, arguments that are returned, error handling, nondeterminism, ...

   In this situation, a benefit of using the reader or state monad *transformer* is that we can package all of these monads into a single monad transformer stack. We still need monadic style, but now we pay the cost once (use do notation everywhere) and get the benefit often (multiple monads in the transformer stack).
3. Some library functions work for arbitrary monads. For example, the `sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]` takes a list of monadic actions, runs all of them in sequence, and returns the collected result.

   A benefit of using the reader or state (or whatever) monad is that we can use these very generic library functions that work for any monad.

Note that points 1 and 2 only show up in realistic, somewhat large programs. So it is hard to give a small example for this benefit of using monads. Point 3 shows up in small library functions, but is harder to understand, because these library functions are often very abstract.